# Find files containing text recursively in subversion repository

Tags: windows, svn, command-line

How can I recursively run through an entire subversion a repository and list files containing a specific text?

Answer (score 1):

You could use **`ack`** (site: http://betterthangrep.com/ , I like the domain name ;) ):

It does ignore the `.svn` by default and runs on multiple platform, including Windows, being a Perl program.

#### Usage Example:

Find all `#include` files in C programs:

```
ack --cc '#include\s+<(.*)> --output '$1' -h
```

#### Testimonial example:

> "Grepping of SVN repositories was driving me crazy until I found ack. It fixes all of my grep annoyances and adds features I didn't even know I wanted." --

Comment: Looks great but wheres the Windows executable download?

Comment: @Eldblom: http://betterthangrep.com/ack-standalone (the direct perl script, meaning you must have perl installed). You might want to adapt the shebang, though: http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.10/faq/Windows/ActivePerl-Winfaq4.html#What_s_the_equivalent_of_the_she

Answer (score 0):

If you have a subversion client installed, then you will be able to grab all the versioned files with this command :

```
svn info -R repository_root
```

then extract from this list the files (`Path :` field) and then make a `grep` ([like this one](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)) to extract correct files.